# Running a function without any parameters not working

Tags: java, api

I'm trying to run a function without passing any parameters in the function.

```
// This is what I'm trying to run:
cl.ping(null);

// Here's the setup for the `ping()` function:
public void ping(BinanceApiCallback<Void> callback) {
    this.binanceApiService.ping().enqueue(new BinanceApiCallbackAdapter(callback));
}


@FunctionalInterface
public interface BinanceApiCallback<T> {
    void onResponse(T var1);

    default void onFailure(Throwable cause) {
    }
}
```

When I run that, the app crashes with the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.binance.api.client.BinanceApiCallback.onResponse(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

I tried not inserting anything in the parenthesis, but I get an error saying

> ping (BinanceApiCallback`<Void>`) in BinanceApiAsyncRestClient cannot be applied to ()

So they are basically forcing me to add a callback. like so:

```
cl.ping(response -> System.out.println("I just finished ping()"));
```

**Question:**

How can I call `ping()` without passing anything in it?

Comment: what is the wrong with passing callback?

Comment: @lakshman I want to know why I have to, and if there's a way not to.

Comment: @Horay write a class that extends BinanceApiCallbackAdapter that doesn't require a parameter and invokes super with a callback that does nothing.

Comment: @Horay: Then how do you know what happen when response arrived?

Comment: @lakshman That's a good point. But when it's not async, it doesn't have a callback. Why is that?

Comment: @Horay: No matter synch or asynch, You can have call back.right?

Comment: @lakshman the sync class doesn't require a callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know why I have to, and if there's a way not to.

The BinanceApiCallbackAdapter class takes an instance of the BinanceApiCallback , so that it can call the `onResponse` method , if your passing null then when the adapter class tries to call the `onResponse` method , then it will be doing so on null. That is why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do now is using next lambda:

```
response -> {}
```

There is no way to not pass required parameters in java. Not in this case, not in others.

Comment: He's not passing no parameters, he's passing `null`. The gist of you answer is correct though, and the "empty" lambda seems the best solution.

Comment: java forces us to send null if parameter is not needed